# Where do log files locate in pm2 in sudo mode

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, console, sudo, pm2

I'm new to PM2 and ubuntu-related issues.

I'm running an app using `sudo` with the syntax `sudo pm2 start app.js --time`.

However, when I tried to check the files in $HOME/.pm2/logs/app-error.log, I couldn't find any logs related to what I logged in the code. I believe `sudo pm2 start` is different from `pm2 start`, and the log files are only for the `pm2 start`.

My question is, how can I check the logs in `sudo pm2`?

Comment: Have you checked `/root/.pm2/logs/`? Which makes sense, seeing that `sudo` executes a command as the root user.

Comment: I've accessed it and the only folder in root was the snap folder.

Comment: How did you check? Did you happen to simply `ls`? You need the `-a` to show entries starting with a dot. I.e. `ls -a` to show all dir entries.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to check all the hidden files. I can see all the logs in pm2 folder now :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute pm2 as the root user, the logs will be stored in `/root/.pm2/logs/`.

`sudo` executes commands as the root user, and that also entails that the home directory (referred to as `$HOME` or `~`) that the command sees is the root user's home directory, which usually is `/root`.

So, if a program writes logs to the user's home directory, the location of the log files will depend on what user is executing that program.

Answer (score 0):

By default, pm2 will store log files in ~/.pm2/logs.

Comment: Yes, I know about it. But the data stored by `sudo pm2` and `pm2` are two different data. And I don't know where to find those data from `sudo pm2`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the logs location like this:

Generate an ecosystem file:

```
pm2 ecosystem simple
```

Then edit the ecosystem file and add lines for changing the default location:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name   : "My Application",
    script : "./myapp.js",
    error_file : "/var/log/pm2/myapp/err.log",
    out_file : "/var/log/pm2/myapp/out.log"
  }]
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use the command line:

```
pm2 start -n "My application" -o /var/log/pm2/myapp/out.log -e /var/log/pm2/myapp/err.log /path/to/my/application
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's in `/root/.pm2/logs/`. Probably you haven't check them all using `ls -a`